# Magento: get products with set as new from and to

Tags: magento, date, collections, product

I want to get product collection, where for products is set new from and new to attributes. I need to check if today date is in this interval from and to, and if it is - show this products. How can i do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this Magento Core Block: `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_New`. In `_beforeToHtml()`  such a collection is loaded.